# fail2ban-regex not find any text

Tags: linux, iptables

I installed the server **FAIL2BAN** and now can not understand what the problem is.

fail2ban-regex finds no regular expression, even very simple:

```
fail2ban-regex "192.168.1.1" "<HOST>$"
```

AND ansver

```
Running tests
=============

Use regex line : <HOST>$
Use single line: 192.168.1.1


Results
=======

Failregex
|- Regular expressions:
|  [1] <HOST>$
|
`- Number of matches:
   [1] 0 match(es)

Ignoreregex
|- Regular expressions:
|
`- Number of matches:

Summary
=======

Sorry, no match

Look at the above section 'Running tests' which could contain important
information.
```

Tell me please were can bee error?

Answer (score 0):

I've got this:

> Found a match for '192.168.1.1' but no valid date/time found for
>   '192.168.1.1'. Please contact the author in order to get support for
>   this format

So, looks like it need a datetime in example string.

For example, this works good:

```
fail2ban-regex "03-12-2012 12:00:00 192.168.1.1" "<HOST>$"



Running tests
=============

Use regex line : <HOST>$
Use single line: 03-12-2012 12:00:00 192.168.1.1


Results
=======

Failregex
|- Regular expressions:
|  [1] <HOST>$
|
`- Number of matches:
   [1] 1 match(es)

Ignoreregex
|- Regular expressions:
|
`- Number of matches:

Summary
=======

Addresses found:
[1]
    192.168.1.1 (Mon Dec 03 12:00:00 2012)

Date template hits:
0 hit(s): MONTH Day Hour:Minute:Second
0 hit(s): WEEKDAY MONTH Day Hour:Minute:Second Year
0 hit(s): WEEKDAY MONTH Day Hour:Minute:Second
0 hit(s): Year/Month/Day Hour:Minute:Second
0 hit(s): Day/Month/Year Hour:Minute:Second
0 hit(s): Day/MONTH/Year:Hour:Minute:Second
0 hit(s): Month/Day/Year:Hour:Minute:Second
0 hit(s): Year-Month-Day Hour:Minute:Second
0 hit(s): Day-MONTH-Year Hour:Minute:Second[.Millisecond]
2 hit(s): Day-Month-Year Hour:Minute:Second
0 hit(s): TAI64N
0 hit(s): Epoch
0 hit(s): ISO 8601
0 hit(s): Hour:Minute:Second
0 hit(s): <Month/Day/Year@Hour:Minute:Second>

Success, the total number of match is 1

However, look at the above section 'Running tests' which could contain important
information.
```